# Vertical center items in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

How can I align text to the middle in a dropdown menu navbar?

I have this:

[image]

I already try to follow snippets but I don't have success.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span>menu</span>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item">OPTION 1</a>
                <hr class="menu-item--division">
                <a class="dropdown-item">OPTON 2</a>
                <hr class="menu-item--division">
                <a class="dropdown-item">OPTION 3</a>
                <hr class="menu-item--division">
                <a class="dropdown-item">OPTION 4</a>
                <hr class="menu-item--division">
                <a class="dropdown-item">OPTON 5</a>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my actual code
https://codeply.com/p/zNU5s3kyQl

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site. But your question is duplicated throughout SO and I am sure you can find an answer by simply searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below CSS in your `dropdown-item` or add `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center` classes in each `dropdown-item`.

```
.dropdown-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu hr {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  height: 53px;
}

.dropdown-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-item:hover,
.dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #16181b;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span>menu</span>

      <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">OPTION 1</a>
        <hr class="menu-item--division">
        <a class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">OPTON 2</a>
        <hr class="menu-item--division">
        <a class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">OPTION 3</a>
        <hr class="menu-item--division">
        <a class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">OPTION 4</a>
        <hr class="menu-item--division">
        <a class="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">OPTON 5</a>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```